What do the beauty pageant zombies do?
One of the variants of large zombie appears to be a beauty pageant contestant, with a sash that reads 'MISS CONDUCT' (I've also seen one that says 'BEST KAREN').  These zombies periodically produce some red chunks with a particle effect on them.
What are they doing, and what are the red gibs?

